# WooCommerce hook on product page - also showing on category page?

Tags: hook-woocommerce

I hope you can help me out. (I'm a bit of a newbie.)

I have used functions.php to create two extra product fields and then show the input from these fields as well as a contact link/button below the short description on the product page.
Lets call this added content "mycontent" just to make it easier to explain the problem.

The weird thing is that now, if I go to a category page in admin and add anything in the "Description" field - then "mycontent" shows up above the products on the category page...?!

I have no idea how this is even possible?
But I would very much like it to stop...!    ;o)

I have tried adding "mycontent" to my product page via other hooks from this page: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/, but it doesn't show up. The only way it shows up is if I use woocommerce_short_description. But when I do that, it also shows up on category pages (only if there is a description on the category page).

I am confused on a higher level than normal... What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I use in functions.php to display "mycontent":

```
/* Show PDF link, PDF name and Contact Us on product pages */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'showpdflink', 3 );
function showpdflink($description){
    global $product;
    $link1='';
    // Get the custom field value
    $mypdfcol = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'cop_pdflink', true );
    $mypdfnam = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'cop_pdfname', true );

    // Display
    //Build the links for the pdeffers
    if( ! empty($mypdfcol) ){
        $link1='<hr />
                <div class="pdflink">
                <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_13 et_pb_equal_columns">
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/pdf-icon.png" /></div>
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_4">
                <a href="'.$mypdfcol.'" title="Download pdf';

        if( ! empty($mypdfnam) ){       
            $link1=$link1.' for '.$mypdfnam.'';
        }
        
        $link1=$link1.'" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download pdf';

        if( ! empty($mypdfnam) ){
            $link1=$link1.' for '.$mypdfnam.'';
        }
        
        if( ! empty($mypdfcol) ){
            $link1=$link1.'</a></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
        }
    }
    
    /* Show CONTACT US button */
    $link1=$link1.' <div class="contactbutton">
                    <a href="/kontakt-os" title="Kontakt CopyColor">
                        <span class="large">Ring for pris</span><br />
                        <span class="small">Klik her for kontakt</span>
                    </a>
                </div>';

    /* Show everything on the product page */
    return $description.$link1;
}

/* End of Show PDF link */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone else can use it:

It turns out that woocommerce_short_description is used in several different places and then outputted in different hooks - so it showed up in both the product and the category description.

The correct place for me was woocommerce_single_product_summary.

My problem was that it wouldn't output the code. But by changing

return $description.$link1;

to

echo $description.$link1;

I got it to work.